# expected ")" before numeric constant arduino with potentiometer and leds

Tags: arduino

I'm trying to do potentiometer with LED-s and for every 341 1 LED turns on.When I try to upload it gives me the same error message and I don't know how to solve it.Can you take a look at this?Here is code :

```
int led1 = 4;
int led2 = 3;
int led3 = 2;
int pot  = A0;

void setup(){
  Serial.begin(9600);
  }

void loop(){
  Serial.println(analogRead(pot));
  delay (1);
 if (analogRead(pot)<0);
 {
  digitalWrite(led1, LOW);
  digitalWrite(led2, LOW);
  digitalWrite(led3, LOW);
  }

 if (analogRead(pot)>1 && (pot)341<);
 {
  digitalWrite(led1, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(led2, LOW);
  digitalWrite(led3, LOW);
  }

 if (analogRead(pot)>341 && (pot)682<);
 {
  digitalWrite(led1, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(led2, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(led3, LOW);
  }

 if (analogRead(pot)>682 && (pot)1024<);
 {
  digitalWrite(led1, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(led2, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(led3, HIGH);
  }
}
```

Here is error message :

> pot_3_led:20: error: expected ')' before numeric constant
>
> if (analogRead(pot)>1 && ((pot))341<);
>
> ^
>
> pot_3_led:27: error: expected ')' before numeric constant
>
> if (analogRead(pot)>341 && ((pot))682<);
>
> ^
>
> pot_3_led:34: error: expected ')' before numeric constant
>
> if (analogRead(pot)>682 && ((pot))1024<);
>
> ^
>
> exit status 1 expected ')' before numeric constant

Can you please help me how to solve it, please?

Comment: How to solve it? Open the first C++ tutorial you can find and learn how conditions and operators works. And `1 < analogRead(pot) < 341` won't work either. Also `analogRead` won't return negative value.

Comment: Does `((pot))341<` really look like a valid syntax to you? What is it even supposed to do?

Answer (score 0):

try

```
 if (analogRead(pot)<0)

 if ((analogRead(pot)>1) && (analogRead(pot)<341))

 if ((analogRead(pot)>340) && (analogRead(pot)<682))

 if ((analogRead(pot)>681) && (analogRead(pot)<1024))
```

Comment: There is no need to call `analogRead` for every comparison.

Comment: And `0` value is still uncovered.

Answer (score 0):

Replace your code with this:

```
 if (pot<0);
 {
 digitalWrite(led1, LOW);
 digitalWrite(led2, LOW);
 digitalWrite(led3, LOW);
 }

if ((pot > 1) && (pot < 341));
{
digitalWrite(led1, HIGH);
digitalWrite(led2, LOW);
digitalWrite(led3, LOW);
}

if ((pot>341) && (pot<682));
{
digitalWrite(led1, HIGH);
digitalWrite(led2, HIGH);
digitalWrite(led3, LOW);
}

if ((pot>682) && (pot<1024));
{
digitalWrite(led1, HIGH);
digitalWrite(led2, HIGH);
digitalWrite(led3, HIGH);
}
```